# Firebase UpdateEmail returning updateEmail failed: First argument "email" must be a valid string

Tags: firebase, vue.js

I have a email field in my vue js componont. When the component loads its taking the email value what i have added during the registration time. But when I tried to update my email to a new emai using updateEmail its retruning an error **code: "auth/argument-error", message: "updateEmail failed: First argument "email" must be a valid string."**.

```
    <template>
    <div>
    <form @submit.prevent="onUpdateProfile">
    <input type="email" v-model="profile.email" placeholder="Enter Your Email..." class="from-input" />
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>
    </div>
    </template>

    data() {
        return {
          profile: {
            email: ""
          }
        };
      },


    methods:{
    onUpdateProfile() {
          firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
            if (user) {
                user.updateEmail({
                  email: this.profile.email
                })
                .then(() => {})
                .catch(error => {
                  console.log(error);
                });
            }
       }
    },

created() {
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
     if (user) {
       this.profile.email = user.email;
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you try changing this

```
user.updateEmail({
                  email: this.profile.email
                })
```

to this?

```
user.updateEmail(this.profile.email)
```

Comment: After changing the function I am getting this error when trying update email   ----      message: "This operation is sensitive and requires recent authentication. Log in again before retrying this request."

Comment: this is normal and a security measurement of firebase. In order to do this you also need to get user password and call `user.reauthenticateWithCredential(firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(email, password))`  method then the update method

Comment: So I will remove the updateEmail function and add this function -- user.reauthenticateWithCredential

Comment: no that will stay but call them in order. something like `user.reauthenticateWithCredential(firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(email, password)).then(() => user.updateEmail(email);)` first one will do the reauth part and the second one will do the update

Comment: I have modified the function to this  -  user.reauthenticateWithCredential(firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(user.email, user.password)).then(() => user.updateEmail(this.profile.email))         ----    now it's showing credential failed: Second argument "password" must be a valid string.

Comment: how you are passing the password? or have you checked that password is there?

Comment: you can't get password from user object btw, you should get that from the form like profile.name

Comment: In this case I dont have password field in this page. This methods expects two arguments but I have one only

Comment: you need to add that. or you need to log the user out then ask for to login again so you can have a recent login to do the update.

Comment: does firebase any other function to update an user email?

Comment: as far as I know, no.