# How to update email and sensitive data properly in Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a code where the user can update his credentials/personal information however I encounter a problem and managed to fix it, it was saying first argument had to be an string and I found a solution however I got an error afterwards saying "This operation is sensitive and requires recent authentication. Log in again before retrying...

[image]

Afterwards I found in some of the comments where I found my [first solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59227857/firebase-updateemail-returning-updateemail-failed-first-argument-email-must-b) the following:
`user.reauthenticateWithCredential(auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(user.email, user.password)).then(() => user.updateEmail(email))` I tried to use this but is not working I get other error afterwards and wanted to know if this was either outdated or I'm just doing this wrong.

[image]

**Code**

I get my auth from my firebase.js

```
const db = firebase.firestore();
const auth = firebase.auth();
const storage = firebase.storage();
```

I get my user from my App.js and then if I need it I just send it just like this:

```
function App() {

const [user, setUser] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged((authUser) => {

      if (authUser) {
        setUser(authUser);
      } else {
        setUser(false);
      }
    })
  }, [])

return (
....
<Route path = "/Update_Profile">
            <Inicio user={user}/>
            <UpdateProfile user={user}/>
          </Route>
...
)}

export default App;
```

```
const updateEmail = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        
        if (user && (email != "")) {
            user.reauthenticateWithCredential(auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(user.email, user.password))
            .then(() => user.updateEmail(email))
            
            const ref = db.collection("usuarios").doc(user.uid)
            ref.update({
                email: email
            })
        } else {
            //User is not logged in, handle that case here
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please include where you are defining the `user` and `auth` objects.

Comment: I just added it

Comment: You should look into how to make use of [React Contexts](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) for passing your user down to child components. A somewhat complex but robust example of a user context is included [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68871889/3068190). As this seems to be a new project, you should also transition to using the [modular Firebase SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade) instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `auth` is **an instance of the Auth module** and not the **namespace of the Auth module** from the Firebase Web SDK (because you've used `const auth = firebase.auth()`), the following value is `undefined`:

```
auth.EmailAuthProvider
```

This is because the [`firebase.auth.Auth` class](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.auth.Auth) does not define a property `EmailAuthProvider`. This then means JavaScript tries to call `undefined.credential(...)` and throws an error.

To access the [`EmailAuthProvider` class](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider), you need to access it from the `firebase.auth` namespace directly:

```
firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider
```

In short,

```
firebase.auth !== firebase.auth()
```